# Random proxies not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a model called Proxies, where I store my proxies.

I want Nokogiri to fetch a random proxy with the IP and port everytime Nokogiri opens a webpage.

This is my code:

```
total_proxies = @proxies.count
random_proxies = rand(total_proxies - total_proxies..total_proxies -1)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page.uri, :proxy => '#{random_proxies.ip}:#{random_proxies.port}'))
```

What am I missing here? When I try to run it give me this error:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): #{random_proxies.ip}:#{random_proxies.port}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single quotes for your string argument to :proxy.  You need double quotes so the `#{}` gets interpolated.  Like so:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page.uri, :proxy => "#{random_proxies.ip}:#{random_proxies.port}"))
```

Comment: You should provide an example showing what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> I want nokogiri to fetch a random proxy...

You don't understand how Nokogiri works. It fetches nothing. Ever. It can *read* an open file or it can take a string, but it doesn't know how to "fetch" anything.

That job falls on [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) in your code, which is patching the Kernel's [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/Kernel.html) method to understand URLs. OpenURI returns an open file to Nokogiri which then reads from it. So, that removes Nokogiri from the problem of fetching anything. Read the error

```
bad URI(is not URI?)
```

more closely and you'll see that it's from OpenURI, not Nokogiri.

*As [@PhilipHallstrom said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908216/nokogiri-with-random-proxies-not-working/27908410#27908410)* (give him the credit, not me), the real problem is you're using single-quotes instead of double-quotes to wrap your interpolated string. Consider this:

```
class RandomProxies
  def ip 
    '127.0.0.1'
  end

  def port
    42
  end
end

random_proxies = RandomProxies.new

'#{random_proxies.ip}:#{random_proxies.port}'
# => "\#{random_proxies.ip}:\#{random_proxies.port}"

"#{random_proxies.ip}:#{random_proxies.port}"
# => "127.0.0.1:42"
```

---

> ...correct me if I am not wrong dosen open-uri close the connection. since after it opens up the proxy for each page I get this error "503 Too many open connections".

No, Nokogiri doesn't close the connection; I don't really think that's its responsibility either.

You can look at the [`parse`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#parse-class_method) and [`read_io`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#read_io-class_method) source-code to confirm this, and/or, if you're on Linux you can run a little test:

1. Create a simple XML file on your disk.
2. Start IRB and load Nokogiri:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'
   ```
3. Tell Nokogiri to parse the document using:

   ```
   Nokogiri::XML(open('path/to/file.xml'))
   ```
4. Switch to the command-line in *another* shell and run:

   ```
   lsof | grep path/to/file.xml
   ```

   The `lsof` command will show Ruby still has the file open, though Nokogiri read it. ("lsof" stands for "list open files").
5. Quit IRB and run the `lsof` command again. You'll see it's been closed since the file doesn't show up.

The reason you're getting the problem is because you're opening a bunch of files and not closing them. Often/usually we can get away with not closing them because there's a good number of available file handles and the code won't exhaust those before it exits. But that's not *really* good programming practice. We *should* explicitly close them, or rely on methods/structures that do close the file when they're done.

Because you're using Nokogiri to parse the file into a DOM, Nokogiri will read the entire file into memory to process it. In that case, instead of simply using `open`, use `open` followed by `read` which will close the file once it's done. From the documentation:

> read ensures the file is closed before returning.

Or, you can put your parsing of the document, whether it's a file or being read from a network URL, into a block so it's automatically closed. Something like this untested code should work:

```
require 'open-air'
%w[urls to read].each do |url|
  open(url) do |xml|
    dom = Nokogiri::XML(xml) 
    # do something with the dom
  end
end
```

Remember that [using a block with `open` ensures that the file will be automatically closed](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-open) when the block exits.

> If a block is specified, it will be invoked with the IO object as a parameter, and the IO will be automatically closed when the block terminates. The call returns the value of the block.

That should keep the "503 Too many open connections" problem from happening because your code will only have one connection to the host open at a time.

If you are requesting that many pages that you run out of connections, an alternate solution is to use [Typhoeus and Hydra](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), which can grab the URLs in parallel, and can be told how to throttle the connection. (You *ARE* restricting your requests to a reasonable rate aren't you? If not, you deserve the 503 errors.)

Comment: ahhhh, so all the http request is done by open uri. Thank you so much for the explanation. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's important to understand so you can substitute different data sources and it won't seem like you're dealing with black magic or voodoo.

Comment: I managed to fix this random proxy function, but correct me if I am not wrong dosen open-uri close the connection. since after it opens up the proxy for each page I get this error "503 Too many open connections". Now any chance that you can point me in the right direction here ?

Comment: Manged to fix that one to, now I only need to figure out how to move to the next proxy if the readtimeout => 10

Comment: @CyrusZei, see the added information about using `open`.